# Releveling a factor with a variable that points to the levels variable

Tags: r, factors, forcats

I want to relevel a factor in R using a variable that points to the variable that has the vector of variables to relevel by.

```
library(tidyverse)
response = fct_relevel(response, <variable containing name of vector variable>)
```

I'm doing this because I have a lookup table where I can pull the name of the variable that contains the vector which I would like to use to relevel my factor. As an example, here's a lookup table by `question_group` and each `question_group` has its own vector to which to relevel with.

```
# a lookup table where I can get the level for each question group
levels_lkup <- tibble(question_group = c("A", "B", "C"),
                         factor_level = c("level_1", "level_2", "level_3"))
```

For example, here are the three factor vectors.

```
# define factor levels
level_1 <- c("Excellent", "Fair", "Poor")
level_2 <- c("Positive", "Neutral", "Negative")
level_3 <- c("Happy", "Indifferent", "Sad")
```

In this reprex, I want to use level_1 Excellent/Fair/Poor.
I'm storing the factor_level for question group A.

```
# pull the level for question group A. (The problem is that this pulls "level_1" in quotes)
this_level <- levels_lkup %>% 
  filter(question_group == "A") %>% 
  pull(factor_level)
```

The problem is that when I use `this_level` in `fct_relevel`, it does not evaluate because it is evaluation `this_level` as the character `"level_1"` instead of a refence to the vector `level_1` defined above.

```
# my data of id numbers, q_a1, and q_a2
df_foo <- tibble(id = c(1:6),
                 q_a1 = c(rep("Excellent", 3), rep("Poor",3)),
                 q_a2 = c(rep("Fair", 3), rep("Poor",2), NA)) %>% 
  # notice that there are unknown levels, because each variable does not have at least one of each factor level
  # meaning, once I pivot_longer, the new variable will need to be relevelled.
  mutate(q_a1 = fct_relevel(q_a1, level_1),
         q_a2 = fct_relevel(q_a2, level_1)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "key", values_to = "response") %>% 
  # I can't use "this_level" as a pointer to level_1. This does not relevel the factor.
  mutate(response = fct_relevel(response, this_level))
```

Can I relevel a factor using this pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want `response` to be a factor with `level_1` levels then just do this:

```
df_foo <- tibble(id = c(1:6),
                 q_a1 = c(rep("Excellent", 3), rep("Poor",3)),
                 q_a2 = c(rep("Fair", 3), rep("Poor",2), NA)) %>% 
  mutate(q_a1 = q_a1 %>% factor(level_1),
         q_a2 = q_a2 %>% factor(level_1)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "key", values_to = "response")

df_foo$response
```

```
[1] Excellent Fair      Excellent Fair      Excellent Fair      Poor      Poor      Poor      Poor      Poor      <NA>     
Levels: Excellent Fair Poor
```